# Apache 2: Negative FilesMatch / FilesNotMatch

Tags: apache-2.2, regular-expressions

If I want to apply a rule to only some files in apache2.conf, I can use <FilesMatch>.

For example:

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mpg|avi)$">
    deny from env=hotlink
</FilesMatch>
```

But is there a opposite to FilesMatch, i.e. a FilesNotMatch?

What I want to achieve is:

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mpg|avi)$">
    <FilesNotMatch "ban">
        deny from env=hotlink
    </FilesNotMatch>
</FilesMatch>
```

(deny hotlinking of all images on a server BUT banners)

Or do you have a suggestion how I could modify my regexp to not match anything that contains "ban" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly there doesn't seem to be a way to negate a file match in Apache.

However, the regular expression library that Apache uses is PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). This means you have the full power of Perl's regexes, including their [negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). These are fairly complicated and powerful features. I can't be certain that this will work, especially without knowing the full layout of your images, but you might be able to use something like:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!ban).*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mpg|avi)$">
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct - you need to use `\b(?!.*ban.*)(.+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mpg|avi)$` regexp for such exception.

Comment: I tried "\b(?!/test.php)" to match any file other than test.php and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, you just need to follow my example. As you've ignored 'ending$' (and escaping dot via '\.') you have probably did some tests earlier - up to the point, where rexexp fails, but somehow your comment doesn't specify the place, where it happens. I won't reproduce your test-case, but I might *guess* it has something to do with '/' you've introduced...

Comment: Thanks! I almost always have trouble with regexps. Now I'm trying ^(?!(test\.php))$ and this still doesn't work. It doesn't match "xx" when it should. I'm using the online regexp tester https://regex101.com/ to test. And when I try your example, it matches "a.gif" when it should not match. Probably, I'm not understanding the original question, and misunderstanding the ?! operator.

Comment: Consider ^(?!(test\.php))$ - if you remove the negation, that doesn't match your "xx", what's left? ^()$ - i.e. empty string. Try ^(?!(test\.php)).+$. As for my example - it's supposed to match "a.gif", but do not match "ban.gif" and that is what happens. The accepted answer matches "ban.gif" and so is wrong...

Comment: If you ask me, the Perl Regular Expression library, and all the products that use it, need a true negation operator. Trying to force a "look-ahead" feature to work well can obviously be done, but only with great difficulty. PCRE needs to be extended.