# FilesMatch to disable access to other extensions

Tags: apache-2.2

I put this in httpd.conf

Reloaded apache.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm expecting no files to be accessible from browser except image files, but I can access no probs test.php

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it backwards.  That config **denies** access to all image files and **allows** access to all other files.

[You can create negative regular expressions](https://serverfault.com/questions/78624/apache-2-negative-filesmatch-filesnotmatch) to do what you want or you can [change the order](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) (and hence logic) of your allow,deny directives.